# Emacs lisp: is it possible (using lisp) to run command in an eshell working in other buffer?

Tags: shell, emacs, lisp, g++, elisp

I have a running instance of `eshell` in one buffer and I am writing c++ source in another one. I had bound `compile` to `<F5>` and I am wondering if it is possible to run the output file (of the compilation) in an eshell instance running in another buffer?

If not, then maybe there is a way to open eshell in new frame and automatically run the output of compilation in it?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, if you want to run something after the compilation has finished, you add it to the compilation command. For example, instead of

```
M-x compile RET make RET
```

You might type

```
M-x compile RET make && ./test RET
```

or you might add the program to some appropriate target in your makefile, so you can do

```
M-x compile RET make test RET
```

Maybe if you can explain why you want to run the compiled program in eshell, I could offer you better advice.

---

However, if you insist on using eshell, you might be able to use `compilation-finish-functions`:

> Functions to call when a compilation process finishes. Each function is called with two arguments: the compilation buffer, and a string describing how the process finished.

This isn't all that well documented, but the string is `"finished\n"` if the process finished successfully. So you might do something like this:

```
(defun run-compilation-output-in-eshell (buf msg)
  "If compilation finished successfully, switch to eshell and execute a command."
  (when (string= msg "finished\n")
    (eshell)
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (eshell-kill-input)
    (insert "echo command goes here")
    (eshell-send-input)))

(add-hook 'compilation-finish-functions #'run-compilation-output-in-eshell)
```

This seems rather rude, though: if you happen to be typing into the `eshell` buffer when the compilation finishes, then this deletes your input. As I said above, a bit more context might be helpful.

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much for the answer - the function at the end of your post does the trick. It is not relevant right now, but the context is that I am writing lots of simple source files in c++ (spoj / topcoder) which can be easilly compilled by `g++ source.cc` - it is just easier to me to automatically run the file so I can test it.

Comment: I understand that, but I don't yet understand why you need to run the compiled program *in eshell*. Is it because you need to interact with the compiled program via a command-line?

Comment: I am working in emacs in home and at work - at work I have very limited privileges on my pc (win xp) and eshell is the closest thing to the Unix shell that I can get. Plus, it is in Emacs so there are less keystrokes to play with it and as I just need a shell with few basics commands - it is enough for me. Also - I was wondering how this hack can be done;)

Answer (score 2):

Since it's Emacs, it's possible, but would require some Elisp hacking.

In the meantime, I'd suggest going the easy route by binding to `F5` a macro that will do the following; assuming you hit `F5` in c++ buffer:

1. switch to eshell buffer
2. run the compilation command for your program
3. switch back to c++ buffer